# How to make application building blocks thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have lots of legacy code, which to a large extent consists of classes with following structure:

```
public interface MyFunctionalBlock
{
    // Setters for the inputs
    void setInput1(final int aInput1);
    void setInput2(final Object aInput2);

    // Inside the method run inputs are converted into results
    void run();

    // If this building block needs functionality from some other building blocks,
    // it gets a reference to them from the Google Guice injector.
    void setInjector(final Injector aInjector);

    // Getters for the results
    long getResult1();
    Object getResult2();
    Map<String,String> getResult3();
}

public class MyFunctionalBlockFactory implements Factory<MyFunctionalBlock>
{
    public MyFunctionalBlock create()
    {
        return new DefaultMyFunctionalBlock();
    }
}

class DefaultMyFunctionalBlock implements MyFunctionalBlock
{
    private int input1;
    private Object input2;
    private long result1;
    private long result2;
    private Map<String,String> result3;
    private Injector injector;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Here the calculations are performed.

        // If this functional block needs another one, it gets a reference to it using the injector.
        // AnotherFunctionalBlock is the public interface. Implementations of the interface are 
        // intentionally hidden using injector and package-private declaration.
        final AnotherFunctionalBlock fb = injector.getInstance(AnotherFunctionalBlock.class);

        // First, we set the inputs

        fb.setInput1(...);
        fb.setInput2(...);

        [...]

        fb.setInputN(...);

        // Now we run the calculation

        fb.run();

        // Now we can use the results
        fb.getResult1();
        fb.getResult2();

        [...]

        fb.getResultN();
    }

    // Implementation of getters and setters omitted
}
```

Basically, the entire application consists of such building blocks, which use each other.

Up to now, the application was used in a single-threaded mode. Now I need to modify it such that

1. the building blocks are thread safe and
2. the changes to the code, which uses them are minimal (ideally, I would change only the inner workings of the building blocks without touching the public interfaces and calling routines).

How can I do this?

I thought about putting the code from setting the first input to reading the last result into `synchronized` block (something like the code example below), but it would require rewriting the entire application.

```
final AnotherFunctionalBlock fb = injector.getInstance(AnotherFunctionalBlock.class);

synchronized(fb)
{
    fb.setInput1(...);
    fb.setInput2(...);

    [...]

    fb.setInputN(...);

    fb.run();
    fb.getResult1();
    fb.getResult2();

    [...]

    fb.getResultN();        
}
```

**Update 1 (09.06.2013 21:57 MSK):** A potentially important note - the concurrency stems from the fact that there are N web services, which receive a request, then use the old code to make calculations based on that request and return the results to the web service client.

A potential solution would be to add some sort of queue between web services and the old code.

**Update 2:**

I thought about how to make my code thread-safe with minimum possible effort and found following solution (currently, I don't care about performance).

There are several web service classes, which all have a backend property and access it concurrently.

```
public class WebService1
{

  private Backend backend;

  public Response processRequest(SomeRequest1 request)
  {
    return wrapResultIntoResponse(backend.doSomeThreadUnsafeStuff1(request.getParameter1(), request.getParameter2()));
  }
}

public class WebService2
{ 
  private Backend backend;

  public Response processRequest(SomeRequest2 request)
  { 
    return wrapResultIntoResponse(backend.doSomeThreadUnsafeStuff2(request.getParameter1(), request.getParameter2(), request.getParameter3()));
  }
}
```

All calls to the non-threadsafe code go via the `Backend` class (all web services reference one and the same `Backend` instance).

If I ensure that the backend processes one request after another (and never processes two requests simultaneously), I can achieve the desired result without re-writing the entire application.

Here's my implementation of Backend class:

```
public class Backend
{ 
    private synchronized boolean busy = false;

    public Object doSomeThreadUnsafeStuff1(Long aParameter1, String aParameter2)
    {
        waitUntilIdle();

        synchronized (this)
        {

            busy=true;

            // Here comes the non-thread safe stuff 1

            busy=false;

            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public Object doSomeThreadUnsafeStuff2(Long aParameter1, String aParameter2, Map<String,String> aParameter3)
    {
        waitUntilIdle();

        synchronized (this)
        {

        busy=true;

        // Here comes the non-thread safe stuff 2

        busy=false;
        notifyAll();
        }
    }
    private void waitUntilIdle()
    {
      while (busy)
      {
        wait();
      }
    } 
}
```

Can this solution work?

Comment: The best bet for thread safety is to make your object instances immutable... But given the use of beans you won't be able to do that. Unless you can transform the code so as to use builders.

Comment: I guess the central point is the implementation of setInput* and getResult*. Please tell more what these methods do. Do setinput* take values from getResult* of other functional blocks?

Comment: It looks like the whole thing has been written without thread safety in mind at all - so it will probably require substantial changes (not just adding `synchronized` here and there)...

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov `setInput*` and `getResult*` are simply getters and setters for the respective property. They have no other logic (the logic is encapsulated inside the `run` method). The calling routines sets the inputs using set methods, then invokes the `run` method (which reads data from the inputs and writes results into result properties) and then invoke get methods to read the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing in "Update 2" is similar to the [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). If you're 100% sure that you don't care one tiny bit about performance--and I mean potentially **really bad performance**--and never will, then what you're suggesting is a fair solution, though your proposed implementation has problems around the locking (or lack thereof) around `busy` and the `wait()`. You may be better served by taking a look at [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/intro/getting-started-first-java.html) or another Actor framework.

Think of an Actor as something that runs in a single thread and has a FIFO queue that you can deliver units of work to. For each unit of work, the Actor processes it in some way and then sends back a reply, and you're guaranteed that units of work are processed serially and not in parallel.

What you've dubbed your "Backend" would be the code running in one or more Actors, each separate from the others. A framework like this would allow you take an approach similar to what you've described but with the possibility to scale up to increase performance without too much effort and without requiring you to manage the concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish beyond "making it multi-threaded". Concurrency in Java is a very complex subject, and you're not going to find a single, step-by-step answer for how to convert an entire application from single- to multi-threaded. If you do, I'd mistrust that answer thoroughly. I suggest you pick up ["Java Concurrency in Practice"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601), the de facto reference for such things. That's how you'll learn what you need to know in order to tackle this problem.

Comment: +1 - I voted to close the Q as it is, as you note, far too broad. But I am upvoting this answer as it is the best and appropriate response.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart I made my question more concrete. See update 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution in update 2 will make the *overall application* thread-safe.  I would summarize it as putting a facade/singleton layer between the web users and the actual business code.  The legacy code itself is **not** becoming thread safe, you'd have to rewrite it for that, but since you are completely controlling access to it and executing it in a single threaded fashion, you are overall ok.  If there's any uncontrolled access to the underlying business code, it'll obviously fail.

You say that "currently, I don't care about performance".  I hope you're right about that, because in terms of lock contention this is a horrible idea.  But if all you're trying to do is expose this unsafe code as a web service, and not provide simlutaneous access, then yes, putting a synchronizing singleton facade on top will work.